# Very Basic Question - Propagation of Error and Fold Changes in Medicine

Tags: uncertainty, measurement, error-propagation

Say you have measured three conditions (x, y, and z) together and at three separate times (three replicates). These raw values are normally distributed and in a linear space.

You use those three measurements to determine a mean value of x, y, and z and then express the fold change of y and z compared to x; otherwise known as a ratio. You then will hope to plot those ratio/fold change values on a graph.

Problem is that you want to communicate the error associated with the mean you've calculated, with error bars. I've come across limited examples whereby people will propagate error; they will calculate the limits of the mean in the raw data (standard deviation) and add or subtract that to the mean value and then generate a fold change value for the mean, mean+sd, and the mean-sd to plot.

Is this what you guys would consider OK practice?

I can't seem to get good learning material on this despite the fact that it is incredibly prevalent in medicine.
Additionally I'm starting to think a lot of people are ignoring the above and are calculating standard deviation of individual fold change values, e.g. perform measurements the first time, get a fold change, do it again two more times, plot all three fold changes together and use them to determine error, which seems illogical/bizzare to me.

Hope that makes sense, and thank you again.

Bonus question: on a fold change graph, given the asymmetry, is a geometric mean not more appropriate?

Comment: [This question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/570160) seems to be related.

Comment: I don't really understand your first sentence. What does "together" mean? Does "three times" mean three distinct time points, where watching changes over time is the point of the experiment? Or do you mean you measured each variable in triplicate at one(ish) time point? What is "linear space" in your context? You talk about "fold change" but it is not clear what change you mean. Do you mean to say you compute the ratio of mean of X vs mean of Y (with no "change")?

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for asking for clarification! Three times means three repeats of each measurement, or what would be referred to as biological repeats. Linear space meaning just that the kind of raw values you get are linear, e.g. something like measuring body weight as opposed to measuring doublings of something. And fold change would be that you get a mean of X and use this as the denominator to compute the fold change of Y and Z to X (mean Y/ mean X; mean Z/ mean X) - My sincere apologies for all the confusion, but I hope that helps.

Comment: So, the issue then being if you have three repeats of something (X, Y, and Z) you can get its mean (to use for fold change to X), but is it OK practice to provide the error of that mean as something like (Y+/-standard deviation/X). I ask because of how very, very prevalent the presentation of data in this way occurs in medicine.